# Call pdfium (chrome native pdf viewer) from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension, pdfium

I am aware that pdfium exposes a javascript API ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391198/does-pdfium-expose-its-api-to-javascript-i-want-to-get-the-number-of-current-pa)). But I can't find how to call those functions. On a page with a rendered PDF I can see an embed tag, but I don't know what to do with it.

```
var p =  document.getElementsByTagName('embed')[0]
```

Gives me this:

```
function anonymous()
 __proto__: Object
 <function scope>
```

And in the source code of the Chrome extension, there is this function in pdf.js:

```
  /**
* Handle a scripting message from outside the extension (typically sent by
* PDFScriptingAPI in a page containing the extension) to interact with the
* plugin.
* @param {MessageObject} message the message to handle.
*/
 handleScriptingMessage: function(message) {...}
```

But it only allows the 'selectAll' message.

I would really appreciate if anyone can tell me where can I read more info on this or how to interact with pdfium with javascript

Answer (score 1):

Lu Wang wrote a javascript library for PDFium based on the UI of pdf.js: [Source code on github of PDFium.js](https://github.com/coolwanglu/PDFium.js)

Comment: I also would appriciate more support for javascript. But the developer of PDFium.js looks unavailable. Maybe we should ask more developers to raise the JS support of PDFium.