# JavaScript and pdfium (native Chrome PDF viewer). Can you get current page number

Tags: javascript, api, pdf, pdfium

I'm looking how to get current page of the opened in chrome pdf file via JavaScript.
I've tried this two suggestions:
[caseOne](https://code5.cn/so/javascript/2532469), 
[caseTwo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326644/accessing-pdfium-plugin-methods-with-js-in-chrome-2019)

I'm not sure if I blind or do something wrong, but I can't make it work. So I would be really glad if someone shared if it's possible and how.

I'm going to use it to create useful free and open source Chrome extension, so you would become part of it. Thank you and have a nice day!