# Is there a way to style Google Chrome default PDF viewer

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-color, pdf-viewer

Is there a way to style google chrome default pdf view? I'm trying to change the gray background color to white also make the scroller little bigger for mobile devices if possible.

[image]

I tried to target it on css with no luck

```
// pdf viewer custom style
iframe {
    html {
        body {
            background-color: #ffffff !important;
        }
        #zoom-toolbar {
            display: none !important;
        }
        #zoom-buttons {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like it's creating shadow document on the html but I couldn't find any way to target it

[image]

Comment: this might help - https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/

Comment: The contents of an `iframe` can't be styled - this is in effect a window to an external resource. You can only style or apply attributes to the `iframe` element itself - that's the only part that is actually part of your HTML document's scope.

Comment: Did you accomplish styling PDF Viewer?

Comment: Could you add a snippet with a simple example, so I can edit it? I might have a solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no way to directly style the Chrome default PDF viewer (PDFium). Because the plugin displays and controls content outside the scope of the current page's DOM, it can only be modified by the plugin. As indicated [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication) it is impossible to make modifications to this sort of plugin controlled content unless the plugin also adds a content script that allows the page to pass messages to the plugin; the plugin must additionally be programmed to respond to messages and appropriately update the content. In other words the PDF viewer uses a separate DOM to the page which is not directly accessible. Instead you need to access an implemented API.

In [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/wn49iiOt7iY) discussion Mike West (Google/Chromium dev) states, in answer to a question on DOM accessibility in Chrome's PDF viewer:

> The functionality available in the PDF viewer is (intentionally) fairly limited ... The APIs you're having trouble finding simply don't exist.

Basic API functions are some of those specified by Adobe in their [Parameters for Opening PDF Files](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) and are accessed through the URL (eg `http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=3&pagemode=thumbs`. They are, as indicated above, quite limited, allowing the user to go directly to a page, set zoom factor, show thumbnails etc. Accessing an expanded API through content script messages can potentially be done if you know the available JavaScript messages. A complete list of available JS message names can be determined from the relevant PDFium source [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/pdf/out_of_process_instance.cc) from which it can be seen that advanced styling of the viewer, such as changing colours, isn't possible. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391198/does-pdfium-expose-its-api-to-javascript-i-want-to-get-the-number-of-current-pa) question gives an example of how to implement the API). Certainly there is no access to PDFium's DOM.

This API is deliberately left undocumented; it may change with additions or removals at any time. Thus, while it's possible that in the future there will be an API to let you style some aspects of the viewer, it's very unlikely that any would go so far as to change the background colour or modify a CSS shadow. And, as stated above, without an API you can't modify content controlled by a plugin when you don't have access to its DOM.

---

You may, instead, wish to try [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). It is an open source JavaScript library that renders PDF files using HTML5 Canvas. It is also Firefox's default PDF viewer and is quite capable.

Implementing it as a web app is beyond the scope of this question, but there are many helpful tutorials available. And as you, the developer, will have access to all constituent files, you will certainly be able to style the PDF.js viewer as much as you wish.

Answer (score 11):

**Just paste this into your browser console.**

```
var cover = document.createElement("div");
let css = `
    position: fixed;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #3aa757;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    z-index: 1;
`
cover.setAttribute("style", css);
document.body.appendChild(cover);
```

Comment: This just adds an overlay of some color. Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** Recent versions of Chrome seem to have moved the PDF viewer resources out of `resources.pak` and into the browser binary itself. It should still be possible to download the Chromium source, edit the files described below, and then recompile, but that's much more painful than simply hacking `resources.pak`. Thanks, Google.

As a matter of fact, there is a way, but we've got to get our hands dirty, and the process must be repeated every time we update Chrome. Still, to me, the effort is well worth it. I like to change the PDF viewer's background to white, so that when I activate the color-inverting Deluminate extension at night, I get a nice solid black background. It's so much easier on my eyes compared to the default background, which, when inverted, is blindingly bright.

The Chrome source tree contains thousands of HTML, JS, and CSS files that control the behavior and appearance of many parts of the browser, including the PDF viewer. When Chrome is built, these "resources" are bundled together into a single file, `resources.pak`, which the browser unpacks into memory during startup. What we need to do is unpack `resources.pak` on disk, edit the files that style the PDF viewer, and then repack the bundle.

The first thing we need is a tool that can unpack `resources.pak`. The only one that I know of is [ChromePAK-V5](https://github.com/shuax/ChromePAK-V5). It's written in Go, so we need that to build it. We also need to install a build-time dependency called [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata). Here's how I went about it:

```sh
cd ~/code/chrome
go get -u github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/...
git clone https://github.com/shuax/ChromePAK-V5.git
cd ChromePAK-V5
~/go/bin/go-bindata -nomemcopy -o assets.go assets
go build
cd ..
```

Now that we've got the binary `ChromePAK-V5/ChromePAK-V5`, we can use it to unpack `resources.pak`. In my case, running Chromium on Linux, the file is located at `/usr/lib/chromium/resources.pak`, but it might be somewhere else for you. Once you've found it, copy it, make a backup, and unpack it:

```sh
cd ~/code/chrome
cp /usr/lib/chromium/resources.pak .
cp resources.pak resources.pak.bak
ChromePAK-V5/ChromePAK-V5 -c=unpack -f=resources.pak
```

At this point, the files we need will be located somewhere in the `resources` directory. Now, in the original Chrome source tree, these files all had sensible paths, such as `chrome/browser/resources/pdf/pdf_viewer.js`. Unfortunately, these original paths are not recorded in the `resources.pak` file. `ChromePAK-V5` tries to be clever by using a table that maps the SHA1 hashes of resources files to their original paths, but over time, files change, along with their hashes, and `ChromePAK-V5` can no longer recognize them. If a file is unrecognized, `ChromePAK-V5` will unpack it to, e.g., `resources/unknown/12345`. And, in general, these numbers change from one Chrome release to the next. So, to find the files that we need to edit, we basically need to grep for "fingerprints" that identify them. Let's get started.

The background color of the PDF viewer is controlled by the file which, in the Chrome source tree, is named [chrome/browser/resources/pdf/pdf_viewer.js](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/browser/resources/pdf/pdf_viewer.js). To find the file, grep inside `resources/unknown` for the string `PDFViewer.BACKGROUND_COLOR`. In my case, the file was unpacked at `unknown/10282`. Open this file, and change the line (at/near the end of the file) that sets `PDFViewer.BACKGROUND_COLOR`. I changed it to `0xFFFFFFFF`, i.e., white (which becomes black under Deluminate).

Going further, we can also restyle the PDF viewer's toolbar. By default, the toolbar is dark, so it becomes obnoxiously bright under Deluminate. To fix that, we need to find [chrome/browser/resources/pdf/elements/viewer-pdf-toolbar.html](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/browser/resources/pdf/elements/viewer-pdf-toolbar.html). I found it at `unknown/10307` by grepping for `shadow-elevation-2dp`. What I did was to go to the `#toolbar` block and add `filter: invert(100%);`. Voila, no more blinding toolbar at night.

Finally, if we really want to go all the way, we can get rid of the brief "flash" of the original background color that occurs when loading a PDF. This color is controlled by [chrome/browser/resources/pdf/index.css](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/browser/resources/pdf/index.css), which I found at `unknown/10304` by grepping for `viewer-page-indicator {`. I changed the `background-color` property of `body` to `white` (i.e. black under Deluminate).

The hard part is now over. The final step is to repack the resources and overwrite the system `resources.pak`:

```sh
ChromePAK-V5/ChromePAK-V5 -c=repack -f=resources.json
sudo cp resources.pak /usr/lib/chromium       # or wherever yours should go
```

Now restart the browser and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

A codeless approach is to install a tampermonkey plugin.

https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/437073-pdf-background-color-controller

This is very useful if you are reading a pdf via a browser and just want to change the background color.
[image]

Here shown working in Edge to reduce Harsher Blue Tones at night by upping the Red proportions.
[image]