# Edge Extension that Overrides CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, extension-methods

When a PDF is loaded in Edge there is a Save and SaveAs button I want to remove. This occurs for pdfs loaded from web servers as well as local files.
[image: buttons to remove]

I have the extension loaded and the popup is working, however, I cannot seem to get the CSS to override the page. The CSS needed is:

```
button#save, button#saveAs {   display: none !important;   cursor: not-allowed;   pointer-events: none; }
```

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{

    "name": "CSS Override",
    "version": "0.0.5",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "description": "Override CSS on any website",
    
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/favicon.png"
    },
    
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icons/favicon.png"
        },
        "default_title": "CSS Override",
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
    },
    
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
    
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>", "file:///*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "css": ["css/content.css"],
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the "SaveAs" button removed with custom CSS style added in developer console:

[image: SaveAs button removed]

I hope this is enough information! I've read tons of KBs and googled and asked other developers I know but this is stumping everyone!

**Things I have tried:**

- Read through Chrome documentation on extension building
- Googled different variations of my question and read through forums, blogs, stockoverflow etc,
- Reached out to some professional developers I know (they haven't worked with edge extensions before)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, just like K J said, you can't remove that button, or rather, you just can't style the built-in PDF viewer. It is designed as a plugin, and you can't treat it as DOM, which means it can only be modified by the plugin. You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52354665/19697081) for more details.

If you want to customize a PDF viewer, I suggest you create your own instead of modifying the built-in PDF viewer. You can try some libraries like PDF.js.