# Hide or disable the download button and print button in PDF Viewer in CefSharp

Tags: .net, vb.net, cefsharp

How can I hide the mentioned buttons when using the pdf viewer in CefSharp in WinForms with .NET?

[image]

Comment: Forever since I tried, unless something has changed the options are limited. Your best bet is to search/ask on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php from memory https://stackoverflow.com/a/2105095/4583726 worked once upon a time. There's a pdfium API though I don't think CEF exposes it https://stackoverflow.com/a/31614516/4583726

Comment: For general background please read the first few paragraphs of https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage

Answer (score -2):

You can load your pdf by appending "#toolbar=0" to the URL, It will remove the toolbar completely.